# "apt-get update" always failed to fetch

Tags: apt

I don't understand why this issue could be survive. It display this error message all the time

```
Fetched 32.8 MB in 1min 16s (430 kB/s)                                         
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty-security/universe/binary-i386/Packages  Hash Sum mismatch

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I was tried to using these commands (which found in this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41605))

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/*
sudo apt-get update
```

No luck for me. That dump message show up again. Always failed with `security.ubuntu.com`. My internet connection is OK, I'm able to ping to `security.ubuntu.com` without any trouble.

So, the question here is why? And anyone out there can help me out of this? I'm going to crazy!

Comment: How long has this been going on?

Comment: @Seth: 3 days ago, and this moment.

Comment: Usually it is just a temporary problem with the server and disappears after a few minutes or few hours.

Comment: Have you recreated `/var/lib/lists` and its subdir `/var/lib/lists` after removing them? Try to do it and fetch the lists again `sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial`

Comment: -Seth: Yes, sometime the issue gone, but it always came back to find me....
-TungTran: Did you really read my question? If you really do read it, you will not ask that question.

Comment: see [this page](http://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used) i think the thing that you need is there.

Comment: @ToanNguyen usually this issues shows up on a very low quality network, where data is downloaded corrupted. Be sure to update your system on good quality networks, because if by any accident you download a corrupted package whose hash sum matches the one in a corrupted list, no-one know what will really happen.

Answer (score 23):

Configure your proxy in network settings of your PC for each of items like HTTP, HTTPS, FTP and Socks and apply settings to system wide if you are using proxy.

Remove the existing packages and then try as follows:

```
apt-get clean
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
apt-get clean
apt-get update 
apt-get upgrade
```

([copied from above message](https://askubuntu.com/a/799628/522934))

Answer (score 17):

This worked for me:

```
 apt-get clean
 rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
 apt-get clean
 apt-get update 
 apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: I had to `# mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial` after this

Answer (score 5):

I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and sometimes when I use this command, I encounter with this problem. For solving this you can use the following way:

1. please go to *system settings*.

   [image: system setttings]
2. click on *software & updates*

   [image: software & updates]
3. go to *other software* section. You can find the links that are relative to this error. Uncheck the relative links and click close. If you can't find relative link you can go to *ubuntu software* section and uncheck options that may can relative to this error. Sometimes with changing Download Server to *Main Server* your problem can be solved. For changing download server you can go to *ubuntu software* section and change *Download From* and choose *Main Server*.

Comment: I appreciate your helps, but this absolutely give me no helps. Switch to main server is just simple edit file in /etc/apt/sources.list from xx.archive.ubuntu.com to archive.ubuntu.com. Why? Try to ping archive.ubuntu.com and security.ubuntu.com, they must return you same IP address.

Comment: how do i get to system settings from the command line via ssh -X?

Comment: Step 3 solved the "failed to fetch" problem of the "APT repository for D" on my Ubuntu 14.04.  The error message was "gnutls_handshake() failed: Handshake failed". apt-get update works fine after I uncheck the problematic repository.

Answer (score 5):

Please navigate to

```
/etc/apt
```

then open the `sources.list` file

```
sudo -H gedit sources.list
```

then remove the broken or unavailable package link and save.

Then add a valid one.

Comment: It can be quite challenging to "add a valid one" since the formatting of lines in source files is quite strict, and we may not know where to find the new or correct repository. It may be better to use tools like `add-apt-repository` to do this.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem a week or two ago, and it turned out to be a DNS problem.  I edited my static configuration in `/etc/network/interfaces` and changed the DNS entry to Googles DNS with:

```
dns-nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then rebooted.

Comment: I tried this one first, it worked for me! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Open "Software & Updates" by launching that application or by running this in the command-line:

   ```
   software-properties-gtk
   ```

   [image: Screenshot]
2. Make all four checkboxes are ticked (main, universe, restricted, multiverse), unless you don't want all four sources of software
3. Change the server in control labelled "Download from:" to something else. For some reason, making a change forces APT to refresh the software database in a way that works.
4. Close, and click "Reload" when prompted.

If you prefer, instead of clicking "Reload", you can run this on the command-line:

```
sudo apt update
```