# sudo apt-get update gets Connection failed error but can curl to mirror

Tags: 18.04, updates

I have an Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS VM running on Azure without a public IP due to security restrictions.  I can use curl to download files over HTTP though FTP doesn't work.

These are the errors I'm getting:

```
sudo apt-get update
Err:1 http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive bionic InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
Err:2 http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive bionic-updates InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
Err:3 http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive bionic-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
Err:4 http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive bionic-security InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive/dists/bionic/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive/dists/bionic-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive/dists/bionic-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive/dists/bionic-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 64.106.20.76 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I picked http://mirror.cs.unm.edu since according to [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) it only supports HTTP which in theory should rule out the FTP problem.

I can however access this mirror with curl fine:

```
curl -O http://mirror.cs.unm.edu/archive/dists
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 10616  100 10616    0     0  61011      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 61011
```

I've tried several mirrors with no luck.  AFAIK there's no firewall, proxy or antivirus settings interfering with updating.  All outgoing ports are open.  Also tried all suggestions from [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/711794/apt-get-update-always-failed-to-fetch)

Edit: Regarding DNS setting, as this VM is connected to a intranet with an ExpressRoute there's some kind of magic happening.

First couple of lines of/etc/resolv.conf read:

```
# This file is managed by man:systemd-resolved(8). Do not edit.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "systemd-resolve --status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs must not access this file directly, but only through the
# symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a different way,
# replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search reddog.microsoft.com
```

How can I further debug this problem?

Comment: Also, please try using the `aria2c` command instead of `curl` and please tell me if this works. If `aria2c` works, you can use `apt-fast` which instead of `apt`. The package name is `aria2` but the command is `aria2c`.

Comment: Yup same error, also tried http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu and the original Azure mirror.  Is there some IP address validation etc that occurs when Ubuntu is attempting to fetch packages?

Comment: I don't know of address validation. I do know there is package verification but that is not the error you are getting here.

Comment: Is there a good resource for manually installing aria2 as the problem also stops me getting any packages onto the VM.  Tried DLing the package with curl but bzip2 says it's not a valid bz2 file.

Comment: Added more info in the main post re DNS

Comment: Okay, I have a workaround answer for you below. Just make sure that the dependencies are installed before installing the downloaded `deb` of `aria2`. If the dependencies are not installed, please let me know and maybe we can figure something else out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly I'd like to thank @mchid for adding a lot of valuable information.

As it turns out this was a firewall issue, but one not under my control.

Firstly I was only using `curl` to test connections. When I tried `curl www.google.com` it would work fine, I would get HTML and confirmed it was from google.  When I tried `curl http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test1Mb.db` it would appear to work, ie no errors and a file would be created locally.

However when I tried  `wget http://speedtest.ftp.otenet.gr/files/test1Mb.db` I would get a `ERROR 503: Service Unavailable.` message.  I then tried tweaking HTTP headers etc with no luck.  So it dawned on me that curl may not be working so I checked the downloaded files and low and behold they were all 11kb in size and contained HTML.  That HTML was our intranet's blocked URL message.  Hitting a web end point would work, but any file download was being blocked.

So in my case this is all a result of using an [ExpressRoute](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/expressroute/) to connect an Azure VNet to on-prem network and the restrictions our IT group placed around that.

So the morals of this story are:

- After a week of research if you have a similar issue, it's 98% of the time some kind of firewall issue, 1% DNS, or 1% nuke it from orbit.
- curl may lie to you, use wget
- Just because the Azure connectivity test tool says you can access a URI/port doesn't mean you actually can for real-world usage.
- Try testing downloading files, not just hitting end points with wget
- Make sure the test files you download are valid.  If the file size isn't what you expect inspect the contents.
- Talk to as many local IT people as you can, in my case I had to log a support ticket pretty high up in our org before anyone even knew about the restrictions.

Comment: Yes, my solution was to connect via VPN and then re-run upgrade, went through no problems. Apparently next generation firewalls like Sophos UTM or Checkpoint might block this...

Answer (score 2):

You can use `apt-fast` to install packages instead of `apt` or `apt-get`. `apt-fast` is a wrapper script which uses the `aria2c` command to download packages from the mirrors.

**First make sure the following dependencies are installed before you begin.**

Here is a list of the dependencies you need:

> libc-ares2
>   libc6
>   libgcc1
>   libgmp10 
>   libgnutls30
>   libnettle6 
>   libsqlite3-0
>   libstdc++6
>   libxml2
>   zlib1g

Please run the following command to list the installed packages:

```
for i in $(echo "libc-ares2 libc6 libgcc1 libgmp10 libgnutls30 libnettle6 libsqlite3-0 libstdc++6 libxml2 zlib1g"); do dpkg -l | grep "ii  $i:"; done | sed 's/   .*$//g'
```

**If all of the dependencies are not listed, do not proceed!**

---

**Next**, to install `aria2` please run the following commands:

```
curl -L -O http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/a/aria2/aria2_1.33.1-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i aria2_1.33.1-1_amd64.deb
```

---

**Finally**, to install `apt-fast`, run the following commands:

```
curl -L -O https://launchpad.net/~apt-fast/+archive/ubuntu/stable/+files/apt-fast_1.9.8-1~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i apt-fast_1.9.8-1~ubuntu18.04.1_all.deb
```

Follow the on screen instructions to finish the installation.

---

The commands for `apt-fast` are the same commands used for `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-fast update
sudo apt-fast upgrade
sudo apt-fast install <package name>
```

And if you normally use `sudo apt full-upgrade` or `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, use the following command:

```
sudo apt-fast dist-upgrade
```

---

For more information on `apt-fast` see the following links:

[apt-fast ppa](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast)

[apt-fast on github](https://github.com/ilikenwf/apt-fast)

Also, here is a link to the download page for `aria2`:

[packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/aria2/download)

Please post any errors. Thanks!

Comment: If you would like to uninstall `apt-fast`, use the following command: `dpkg -P apt-fast`

Comment: When I try to list the dependencies I get "E: No packages found"

Comment: @Geordie Thanks, I have updated the command to list the dependencies.