# Error messages: openjdk-8 connection failed/timed out

Tags: networking, apt, package-management, updates, 22.04

I am facing a challenge with this error, and I would greatly appreciate any assistance.

Everything runs smoothly when I execute `sudo apt update`, displaying the message "27 packages can be upgraded." However, issues arise when I proceed with `sudo apt upgrade`, as a few errors are encountered, as shown below:

> want to continue? [Y/n] y
> Ign:1 http:// kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u382-ga-1~22.04.1
> Ign:1 http:// kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u382-ga-1~22.04.1
> Ign:1 http:// kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u382-ga-1~22.04.1
> Ign:1 http:// kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64
> openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u382-ga-1~22.04.1
> Err:1 http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u382-ga-1~22.04.1   Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
> E: Failed to fetch http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u382-ga-1%7e22.04.1_amd64.deb  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.83 80]
> E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?

I attempted to resolve the issue by following the error message and running `sudo apt update --fix-missing`, but unfortunately, the error message remained unchanged.

I have listed all the methods I found online and attempted to debug the problem, but the error persists. **If you have any additional suggestions or solutions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.**

---

### <Attempt 1>

["Failed to fetch security undetermined error ... | askUbuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305141/failed-to-fetch-security-undetermined-error-ip-91-189-91-38-80-in-ubuntu-20-0):

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

I added the following lines to the file editor:

> deb http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal main universe multiverse restricted
> deb http:// security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-security main multiverse universe restricted
> deb http:// archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates main multiverse universe restricted

```
sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoclean
sudo apt update
```

There was no error on running these codes. However, I still received the same error when I attempted to run `sudo apt upgrade`.

---

### <Attempt 2>

["apt-get update" always failed to fetch | askUbuntu"](https://askubuntu.com/q/711794/1718107):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
sudo-get clean
sudo-get update
sudo-get upgrade
```

No errors occurred until `sudo-get upgrade`, and the error remained identical to the one mentioned earlier.

---

### <Attempt 3>

["Install openjdk-8-jdk"](https://moongtaeng.net/wp/2023/03/):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless
```

When executing `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk-headless`, the same error as mentioned above occurred.

---

### <Attempt 4>

["Could not get lock ..."](https://mingyucloud.tistory.com/entry/%EC%98%A4%EB%A5%98-%ED%95%B4%EA%B2%B0-Waiting-for-cache-lock-Could-not-get-lock-varlibdpkglock-frontend):

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
sudo rm /var/cache/apt/archives/lock
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock*

sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt update
```

---

### <Attempt 5>

["Fail to install openjdk-8-jdk | Ubuntu"](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+question/701349):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt clean
sudo apt -y full-upgrade
sudo apt -y install openjdk-8-jdk

sudo apt-get -f install

wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/openjdk-8/openjdk-8-jdk-headless_8u312-b07-0ubuntu1~18.04_amd64.deb
```

---

Based on the information provided by ChatGPT, it is probable that the issue could be related to network stability. Nonetheless, my network functions smoothly, and I can install other packages without encountering any difficulties. Hence, I don't believe network stability is the reason for the problem. Additionally, I followed the suggestion to wait for a day, as it mentioned that server issues or network problems might be temporary and can sometimes resolve themselves after a few days.

As a newcomer to Linux, I am encountering difficulties dealing with these errors. If you have any additional suggestions or solutions, I would greatly appreciate your assistance in resolving this matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply change the server location to resolve this issue. While the default server location typically connects you to the nearest option, proximity doesn't guarantee reliability. Aim to locate a server that strikes a balance between quality and proximity. This adjustment should eliminate the errors.

Keep in mind that specific packages may necessitate particular server locations, so maybe try to mess around with it a bit.

To modify the server, navigate to Software Updater, then access Settings & Livepatch, and finally select Ubuntu Software. From there, adjust the "Download from" setting.