# Ubuntu 23.10 - Update Problems (Some index files failed to download)

Tags: apt, updates

I can't seem to get `apt` to update - aside from having `deb-src` packages enabled and `docker` and `mozilla` repos my apt config should be fairly standard (and it doesn't seem like they're the problem anyway) - anyone know what I can do to fix this?

```
$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-security InRelease
Get:6 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla InRelease [1,350 B]
Get:7 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main amd64 Packages [81.4 kB]
Err:8 https://packages.mozilla.org/apt mozilla/main all Packages
  400  Bad Request [IP: 34.160.78.70 443]
Fetched 81.4 kB in 1s (65.0 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch https://packages.mozilla.org/apt/dists/mozilla/main/binary-all/Packages  400  Bad Request [IP: 34.160.78.70 443]
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Does [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/711794/730458) answer your question?

Comment: @ChuckLiu a simple `apt-get clean` before the update did the trick, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doing `apt-get clean` before trying the update worked, thanks for the link @ChuckLiu

Comment: @zx485 you can't accept comments, so I need to make an answer and want to give credit