# How to fix the error, while updating my package list?

Tags: apt, updates

I get this error when I try to update my **Ubuntu 16.04**.

Error:

```
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**What is this error and How can I fix it ?**

Comment: This has solution for ubuntu 12.04. Hope it works in 16.04 http://askubuntu.com/a/397409/439474

Answer (score 0):

That error will do no harm (at least) but you can remove them manually by doing a `sudo nautilus` and then navigating to `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then delete the files not required , probably the files related to the `upubuntu.com` cause it doesnt have any files for Ubuntu 16.04 .