# How to fix the error, while updating my package list in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: apt, updates

I get this error when I try to update my **Ubuntu 16.04**. I already tried few solutions but nothing worked so far.

**Error:**

```
W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-security/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192
W: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-updates/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise-backports/InRelease: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**After un-checking few of unwanted packages/repositories** from software and update section, I managed to get rid of few of the errors but still few errors are still existing:

```
 The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
 N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
 W: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release.gpg: Signature by key 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
 E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

**After applying the solution** provided below( by Raphael),most errors got resolved. Except these errors:

```
 W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
 N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
 N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
 E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/upubuntu-com/network/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: What are the few solutions that you've already tried?

Comment: solutions provided in this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used/397409#397409

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are using `Xenial` but your `sources.list` contains links for `Precise`. To rectify that,

- Backup your current `sources.list`:

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak
  ```
- Create a new `source.list`:

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- Copy and paste the following into it:

  ```
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted universe multiverse
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse 
  deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
  ```
- Then, on the keyboard press the following:

  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd> then <kbd>Y</kbd> and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
- Finally, try updating your sources:

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  ```

---

**EDIT**:- The `ppa` error is what it says. That `ppa` doesn't have a release file for `Xenial`. To remove `ppas`, please follow this answer at [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed).

Comment: Thanx for the insight and solution. Other errors(new) got resolved by this solution but few errors(old) are still there.

Comment: @Nikhil - Edited my answer. Please follow that link to get rid of that error.