# The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management, updates, update-manager

I know similar problems have already been added but non of them worked for me.

This is how it started:

I was searching Solution for a problem and I applied [this solution from nicktux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329450/e-some-index-files-failed-to-download-they-have-been-ignored-or-old-ones-used)

I'm new to Linux, and using Ubuntu 18.04. I might have blindly input the solution, but now I have bigger problem.

When I type `sudo apt-get update` I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done                                                                                                                
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: C47415DFF48C09645B78609416126D3A3E5C1192
E: The repository 'http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5
```

(Same linkes were repeated.)

I tried `sudo apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 630239CC130E1A7FD81A27B140976EAF437D05B5`

Nothing worked. I'm very much nervous right now, I hope I dont need to format my Laptop AGAIN for similar kind of problem.

Tell me what should i do?

Comment: thats not my problem.

Comment: Regarding your comment: if neither of the questions linked in the duplicate banner contain any answers that solve this, then you can **[edit]** this question to explain that (including details), which may lead to the question being reopened.